# Finding the number of consecutive objects

Tags: combinatorics

Thee are 14 intermediate stations between A and B. A train is to be scheduled from point B to A so that it halts at exactly three intermediate stations, no 2 of which can be consecutive. The number of ways this can be accomplished is ?

My solution involved ${14 \choose 3}$ - 13 ( as thirteen was the number of consecutive pairing of two numbers possible.

Where am I going wrong ?

Comment: Please share your own attempt to solve the problem and indicate where you are stuck.

Comment: plz put some of your own sweat

Comment: So my effort was to try to calculate the total number of ways in which the train can stop and then subtract the number of ways which involved it stopping at consecutive stations .

To do the same I chose 3 objects out of 14 and then subtracted 13 from the answer as there were 13 consecutive pairs.

Comment: Please correct the heading.

Comment: How would you want me to correct the heading ?

Comment: Finding the number of non-consecutive objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Method 1:**  We use eleven blue balls to represent the bypassed stations and three red balls to represent the intermediate stations where the train stops. Line up the eleven blue balls in a row, leaving gaps between them in which to insert the red balls.  There are twelve spaces for the red balls, in the ten spaces between successive blue balls and the two spaces at the ends of the row.  Select three of these twelve spaces in which to place the red balls.  Now label the balls from left to right with the names of the intermediate stations in the order the train encounters them.  The names on the red balls are the three stations where the train stops.  Since there are $\binom{12}{3}$ ways of selecting the positions of the red balls, there are also $\binom{12}{3}$ ways of selecting three intermediate stops for the train so that no two of them are consecutive.

**Method 2:**  We fix your attempt by using the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

There are $\binom{14}{3}$ ways of selecting three of the $14$ intermediate stops.  However, we must exclude those in which at least two of the stops are consecutive.

There are $13$ pairs of two consecutive intermediate stops (since the first of the two consecutive stops cannot be the last stop before the final destination).  For each such choice, there are $12$ ways of choosing the third intermediate stop (which you forgot to take into account).  Hence, there are $13 \cdot 12$ ways to select ctwo consecutive stations.

However, if we subtract $13 \cdot 12$ from $\binom{14}{3}$, we will have subtracted each selection of three consecutive intermediate stops twice, once when we select the first two of the three consecutive intermediate stops and once when we choose the last two of the three consecutive intermediate stops.  Since we only want to exclude these selections once, we must add the number of ways in which three consecutive stops can be selected.  There are $12$ ways of selecting three consecutive intermediate stops (since the first of the three consecutive stops cannot be on of the last two stops before the final destination).

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of ways three of the fourteen intermediate stops can be selected so that no two of them are consecutive is 
$$\binom{14}{3} - 13 \cdot 12 + 12 = \binom{12}{3}$$

Comment: why did you add 12 ?

Comment: @Agawa001  I apologize for the omission.  I have edited the penultimate paragraph to explain that.

Comment: an underlying context of this sentence "no 2 consecutive stations" is inclusive to 3 consecutive stations which compounds 3 pairs, so i think 12 isnt added to the total.

Comment: @Agawa001 As I said above, when I subtracted the $13 \cdot 12$ solutions in which at least two of the stations are consecutive, I removed those solutions in which all three consecutive stations are consecutive twice.  We want to remove them only once, which is why I had to add them back.

Comment: and as i said above too, you dont have to remove/add back this amount since any 3 consecutive stats comprehend atleast 2 stats which are adjacent.

Comment: @Agawa001 Please read about the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle at the link above to better understand what I am saying.  As you can check, both my answers yield the same result of $220$ permissible selections.

Comment: N. F. Taussig you are not talking to a combinatorics newbie, i know you did right removing 13*12 stations using this principle, where the addition is wrong step (atleast as i assume)

Comment: @Agawa001 When we subtract the pairs containing $(x_1, x_2)$ or $(x_2, x_3)$, we subtract the triple $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ twice.  However, we must subtract each instance in which there are at least two consecutive selected stations only once.  Hence, the number of ways of selecting at least two consecutive stations is $13 \cdot 12 - 12$.

Comment: N. F. Taussig thank you so much i apologize for my mind-narrowness, now its perfectly clear, i apopologize for the second time

Comment: @Agawa001 I am glad I finally found a convincing explanation.  Best wishes.

Answer (score 4):

Let the number of stations between the starting point and the first halt be $x_1$, between the first and second halt be $x_2$, between the second and third halt be $x_3$, and between the third halt and the destination be $x_4$.
Now,
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+3\text{(the three stations where the train halted)}=14$$
That is,
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=11$$

Now, no two of these stations will be consecutive if $x_i\ge1$ where $i\in\{2,3\}$

Let $x_2=y_2+1$ and $x_3=y_3+1$. Then, we have $y_2,y_3\ge0$.
Let $x_1=y_1,x_2=y_2$

Thus, the solution will be the number of non negative integer solutions of the equation,
$$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=9$$

Answer (score 1):

*Another way:*

With "non-stopping" station as $\color{green}{\Large\bullet}$ and a "stopping" station as $\color{red}{\Large \bullet}$, add an extra $\color{green}{\Large\bullet}$

Create $3$ boxes, $\boxed{\color{green}{\Large\bullet}\color{red}{\Large\bullet}}\quad\boxed{\color{green}{\Large\bullet}\color{red}{\Large\bullet}}\quad\boxed{\color{green}{\Large\bullet}\color{red}{\Large\bullet}}\,\;$now there are $12$ *objects* in total,

Place the boxes in $\binom{12}{3}$ ways, and remove the extra $\color{green}{\Large\bullet}$ from the first box.

Comment: true blue anil would you like to explain me , Here Total $14$ station, Now if we paring $3$ non halting station and halting station , The We have total $11$ station, But you have mention $12$ station, and you also add one extra non halting station, I did not understand that, Thanks

Comment: One of the paired $\color{green}{\Large\bullet}$ was an *extra* we put in, so from $14$, we subtracted $5$ but created $3$ objects. $14-5+3=12$

Comment: @juantheron  There is a bijection between selections in which we choose three of the $14$ intermediate stations and three of $15$ stations in which we do not choose the first station.  Adding the additional station at the front enables us to select three boxes in which there is a non-stopping station and a stopping station rather than using an Inclusion-Exclusion argument.