# No. of ways a train can stop at four stations out of 12 given stations such that no two are consecutive

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Between two junction stations, there are 12 sub stations. In how many ways a train can stop at 4 of these sub stations such that no two of these halting sub stations are consecutive?

I have no idea from where to start this problem....been thinking of it for quite some time....One possible way would be to subtract the no. of ways in the train halts at at least 2 consecutive stations then add back no. of ways it can stop at at least 3 consecutive stations and finally subtract the no. of ways it can stop at exactly four consecutive stations; from the total no. of ways it can stop at four stations out of the 12 given stations....

But apparently the answer I get from this is wrong...can anyone help me out??
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Related:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665347/finding-the-number-of-consecutive-objects/1665442#1665442

Answer (score 1):

Rephrased you are asked to find the number of sums: $$n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4+n_5=8$$ under the extra condition that $n_1,n_5$ are nonnegative integers and $n_2,n_3,n_4$ are positive integers.

Here e.g. $n_2$ stands for the number of substations in between the first and the second substation where the train stops.

That comes to the same as finding the number of sums: $$m_1+m_2+m_3+m_4+m_5=5$$ under the extra condition that  $m_1,m_2,m_3,m_4,m_5$ are nonnegative integers.

This can be solved with [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Give it a try.

Comment: That gives me 126 as the answer but the answer key mentions the answer as 75

Comment: I think u misunderstood the question....

Comment: That's possible. I go out from stations $0,1,2,\dots,12,13$ where $0$ and $13$ are the end stations. In my answer the train is allowed to stop e.g. at $1,4,6,12$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yep thats correct I dont know where your solution is wrong tho.....the answer is 75.....I got the same answer(126) by arranging the eight stations leaving a gap in between and then the train will have a choice to stop at 4 stations out of the nine options it has.....which gives the answer as 126 but since the answer key says it 75 ...... I asked the question on SE......

Comment: That's nasty of course, but (as you will understand) here it stops. You had a valid reason to ask the question, and uptil now I have more trust in $\binom94=126$ than in $75$.

Comment: I think the problem is with the assumption that all the stations are identical.....and hence we cant use multinomial theorem.....anyways ill check it out later with my professor.....thanks for the help!!

Comment: @drhab i only wants to solve this question by multinational theoram and i know that i need to find coefficient of $n^8$ in expansion of.. but i am failing to define the lower limit and the upper limit of each  substations.in short i am failing to decide in what i need to find the coefficient of $n^8$.